# Swift make input transparent with only border-bottom

Tags: ios, swift

How can I create a textField with transparent background and only border bottom?

I have tried this code:

```
textField.backgroundColor = .clear
let border = CALayer()
let width = CGFloat(2.0)
border.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: textField.frame.size.height - width, width:  textField.frame.size.width, height: textField.frame.size.height)
border.borderWidth = width
textField.layer.addSublayer(border)
textField.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

But it isn't working.

Comment: Define "isn't working".

Comment: @rmaddy it is just showing an empty space

Comment: Xib with constraints-just make a 1 line height box below the text edit. Xib without constraints - do the same, but set the same resize mask as the textfield. No code is needed for any of this, even with the accepted answer by M Dan. I recommend reading these 4: Views, View Controller, Animation, Quartz2D guides from Apple

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an alternative implementation using a UIView rather than a CALayer.

```
let line = UIView()
line.frame.size = CGSize(width: textField.frame.size.width, height: 1)
line.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: textField.frame.maxY - line.frame.height)
line.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
line.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleTopMargin]
textField.addSubview(line)
```

Comment: You smart.You very smart

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct. Problem is only with your border height which is now "textField.frame.size.height" change it to 1.0.(Change your border frame code).

Comment: Note that UIRectEdge type is an OptionSet (it might have more than one edge) so you need to compare it against a Set with a single element when switching its cases. Break it is only needed at the default case (and only if default case is empty).

Answer (score 2):

Please try this :

```
txtField .borderStyle = .none
```

It may help you.... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
extension UITextField {
    func setBottomBorder(borderColor: CGColor = UIColor.white.cgColor,
        backgroundColor: CGColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor) {
        self.borderStyle = .none
        self.layer.backgroundColor = backgroundColor

        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(2.0)
        border.borderColor = borderColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        border.borderWidth = width
        self.layer.addSublayer(border)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

This worked for me.

Then you can just call

```
yourTextField.SetBottomBorder(borderColor: UIColor.white.cgColor, backgroundColor: UIColor.clear.cgColor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line with your code :-

```
   border.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to be working fine for me though, setting the backgroundColor to clear fix this

textField.backgroundColor = .clear